# Could high blood pressure possibly clean the arteries of build-up?

Tags: health-education

If the blood is rushing faster than normal ex. by eating sugar, couldn't it lower the opposite problem - fatty grease build-up clogging the arteries? I'd assume it'd hit more of the atoms off the walls. Would it?

Comment: Ask yourself why high blood pressure is associated with increased risk of heart attack and stroke rather than the other way around.

Comment: It isn't difficult to do some research and present what you've found when asking here; doing so would be helpful in getting a response.  Please see [How do I ask a good question?](http://health.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) Knowing what you know about high blood pressure and plaque formation, what makes you wonder if high blood pressure might help prevent it? Thanks.